# rectangular function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to program this function: $ g(t)= \operatorname{rect}(t/T) \,f(t)$

I take: $t=0:1:20$ and I know how to program $f(t)$.

But I have a problem with the rectangular function. How to program this function in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

```
function y = rect(x);

    x = abs(x);

    if x == 0.5
        y = 0.5;
    else
        if  x < 0.5
            y = 1;
        else
            y = 0;
        end
    end

end
```

put this in a file and name it *"rect.m"*.  make sure it's on your MATLAB search path.

Comment: Just check if you like my edit ...

Comment: hay @MattL., ever read about the [Wicked Blble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wicked_Bible)?  (moral of story:  proofreading by someone else is necessary sometimes.)

Comment: Your original rect.m was indeed pretty wicked ... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to program any function $f(t)$, then you should know how to program a specific function  $\mathrm{rect(t/T)}$.

However, Matlab already have a convenient function for that, `window.m`, which you can pad as desired:

```
N = 65;
w = window(@rectwin ,N);
```

But it is more interesting to exercise interesting features in Matlab, including the function handle `@` for inline functions, and the function `linkaxes.m`, to easily test different options (as for discrete signals, different versions for the rectangular functions coexist):

```
% Choose among four types of discrete rectangular windows
time = (-20:20)'; T = 5;
f = @(t) sin(2*pi*t/30);
nCase = 4;
for iCase = 1:nCase;
    switch iCase
        case 1
            %% Option 1: rectangular is defined as one on ]0,1[
            w = @(t) ((t > 0) & (t < 1));
        case 2
            %% Option 2: rectangular is defined as one  on [0,1]
            w = @(t) ((t >= 0) & (t <= 1));
        case 3
            %% Option 3: rectangular is defined as one  on ]-1/2,1/2[
            w = @(t) (abs(t) < 1/2);
        case 4
            %% Option 4: rectangular is defined as one  on [-1/2,1/2]
            w = @(t) (abs(t) <= 1/2);
    end
    h1(iCase)=subplot(nCase,2,2*(iCase-1)+1) ;
    plot(t,[f(t) w(t/T)],'x-')
    legend('f','w')
    h2(iCase)= subplot(nCase,2,2*(iCase-1)+2);
    plot(t,[f(t).*w(t/T)],'o-')
    legend('f \times w')
    linkaxes([h1,h2],'xy')
end
```

One result is shown below:

[image: functions and products]

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways

Using an inline function

```
clear all
x=linspace(-1,1,1024);
rect=@(x) (sign(x+.5)-sign(x-.5))/2
plot(x,rect(x))
title('rect')
xlabel('x')
```

[image]

rect(t/T) is left as an exercise ( give a man a fish and you feed him for a day, teach him how to fish and he will have an excuse to get out of the house)

Answer (score 1):

`rectangularPulse()` and `triangularPulse()` are built-in functions that can also do this.